# Go array for method

Tags: pointers, methods, go

Can I use array and its pointer for Go methods?

I have the following code:

```
var array = [3]string{"A", "B", "C"}
type arrayTypePt *[3]string
func (m *arrayTypePt) change() { m[1] = "W" }
func main() {
    (arrayTypePt(&array)).changeArray4()
}
```

But this code: http://play.golang.org/p/mXDEhmA9wk

give me an error of:

```
invalid receiver type *arrayTypePt (arrayTypePt is a pointer type)
invalid operation: m[1] (type *arrayTypePt does not support indexing)
arrayTypePt(&array).changeArray4 undefined (type arrayTypePt has no field or method changeArray4)
```

I get the same error when I try this with slice.
Why I cannot do this in method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *receiver* type of a method cannot be a pointer to a pointer, but that is what you wrote:

```
func (m *arrayTypePt) change() { m[1] = "W" }
```

`arrayTypePt` is already a pointer `*[3]string`. Quoting from the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> [The receiver] type must be of the form `T` or `*T` (possibly using parentheses) where `T` is a type name. The type denoted by `T` is called the receiver base type; **it must not be a pointer or interface type** and it must be declared in the same package as the method.

Your 2nd error (*"type *arrayTypePt does not support indexing"*) is also a result of this (`m` is a pointer to pointer, that's why you can't index it; if it would only be a pointer to array or slice, the pointer indirection would be automatic).

Your 3rd error is simply a typo, you declared a method named `change()` and not `changeArray4()`.

So you should only name the non-pointer array type:

```
type arrayType [3]string
```

And you can declare your array using directly this type:

```
var array = arrayType{"A", "B", "C"}
```

And you can simply call its `change()` method:

```
array.change()
```

The address of the array will be taken automatically (because the `change()` method has a pointer receiver but the `array` variable itself is not a pointer).

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/wXV1-Vyc4c).

#### Notes / Alternatives

If you would want your `array` variable to be explicitly `[3]string`, you could still make it work by converting it to `arrayType`, setting it to another variable, and `change()` can be called on this (because being a variable its address can be taken - while the address of a conversion like `arrayType(arr)` cannot):

```
arr2 := [3]string{"A", "B", "C"}
arr3 := arrayType(arr2)
arr3.change()
```

Or if you would declare your variable to be a pointer to type `[3]string`, you could save the required additional variable (which was only required so we were able to take its address):

```
arr4 := new([3]string)
*arr4 = [3]string{"A", "B", "C"}
((*arrayType)(arr4)).change()
```

Try these variants too on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HPvm2k7cDj).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you define the array/slice variable as the receiver type:

```
type arrayType [3]string
var array arrayType = [3]string{"A", "B", "C"}   # note "arrayType" here
func (m *arrayType) change() { m[1] = "W" }
func main() {
    array.change()
}
```

I'm not sure why the typecasting behaves like it does.